# Adding multiple childs belonging to a parent at once

Tags: grails, grails-orm

If I have two domains as below

```
class Author {
  static hasMany = [books: Book]
  String name
}

class Book {
  static belongsTo = [author: Author]
  String color
}
```

How can I add multiple books for an author at the same time?

like Below:

```
def book1 = new Book(color: "white")
def book2 = new Book(color: "black")
def books = []
books << book1
books << book2

def author = new Author(name: "John Doe").addToBooks(books).save()
```

Comment: If your aim is to reduce the lines of code then you can also optimize Burt's code by removing the local list and use `[book1, book2].each{author.addToBooks(it)}` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addToBooks` takes either a `Book` instance or a map that can be used to create a `Book` instance. This is relatively compact:

```
def book1 = new Book(color: "white")
def book2 = new Book(color: "black")
def books = []
books << book1
books << book2

def author = new Author(name: "John Doe")
books.each { author.addToBooks(it) }
author.save()
```